# inequalities by Archimedean property.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

If $y>0$ we are supposed to show there exists $n\in{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $$\frac{1}{2^n}<{y}$$\ now my approach was to apply directly Archimedean property that for any real number $\log_2(\frac{1}{y})$ There exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\log_2(\frac{1}{y})<n$$ but I don't know whether $\log_2(\frac{1}{y})$ is actually real ,can anyone provide any alternative solution to this , thanks.

Comment: Forget the $\log$. **Hint** : $2^n > n$

Comment: You mean '$\frac{1}{2^n}<\frac{1}{n}<y$'that seems so straight forward ,I am so dumb . thank you very much.

Comment: you are welcome $:$)